# Python: Time format into Decimal

Tags: python-3.x

How can I convert the time in HH:MM:SS.SSS format to decimal number in Python? Example: I want to convert the time "00:00:26.94" to a decimal number so that I can use the decimal number as data to graph a chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`plt.plot_date()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date.html#matplotlib-pyplot-plot-date) in combination with [`mdates.date2num()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num).

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates 

d = dt.datetime.strptime("00:00:26.94","%H:%M:%S.%f")
plt.plot_date(mdates.date2num(d),1)
plt.gca().set_xlim((dt.datetime.strptime("00:00:25","%H:%M:%S"),
                    dt.datetime.strptime("00:00:27","%H:%M:%S")))
plt.show()
```

Example plot:
[image]

Comment: Excellent alternative Thanks I am currently using Flask and Chart.js to generate graphics. Is there any way to do the same for Chartjs. Basically I have a database that stores the times obtained in swimming competitions. For example, in the 50 meters freestyle I have no problem since the times are in SS: SS format (example 26.94) and I can generate the graph in Flask with Chart.js. However, in the case of times like 00: 08: 23.78 I need to graph that time with respect to the month in which the time was reached. I still can't imagine the solution with Chart.js. Any guide would be very grateful.

Comment: @Ramiro: You're welcome. I think that this would be different from your original question so maybe you would like to open a new question specifically focused on Chart.js graphing.

Answer (score 1):

```
time = "21:14:05.00"    # Hours, minutes, seconds and hundreds of seconds
(h,m,s) = time.split(':')   # Get hours, minutes and seconds

hours   = float(h)
minutes = float(m)

# Divide the seconds from the hundreds of seconds, and assign in a []
a = s.split('.')
seconds = float(a[0])
hundreds = float(a[1])
decimalt = hours*3600.0 + minutes*60.0 + seconds + hundreds/100.0
print(time)
print (decimalt)
```